# How to run user defined function over a window in spark dataframe?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, outliers, spark-window-function

I am trying to detect the outliers from my spark dataframe.
Below is the data sample.

| pressure | Timestamp |
| --- | --- |
| 358.64 | 2022-01-01 00:00:00 |
| 354.98 | 2022-01-01 00:10:00 |
| 350.34 | 2022-01-01 00:20:00 |
| 429.69 | 2022-01-01 00:30:00 |
| 420.41 | 2022-01-01 00:40:00 |
| 413.82 | 2022-01-01 00:50:00 |
| 409.42 | 2022-01-01 01:00:00 |
| 409.67 | 2022-01-01 01:10:00 |
| 413.33 | 2022-01-01 01:20:00 |
| 405.03 | 2022-01-01 01:30:00 |
| 1209.42 | 2022-01-01 01:40:00 |
| 405.03 | 2022-01-01 01:50:00 |
| 404.54 | 2022-01-01 02:00:00 |
| 405.27 | 2022-01-01 02:10:00 |
| 999.45 | 2022-01-01 02:20:00 |
| 362.79 | 2022-01-01 02:30:00 |
| 349.37 | 2022-01-01 02:40:00 |
| 356.2 | 2022-01-01 02:50:00 |
| 3200.23 | 2022-01-01 03:00:00 |
| 348.39 | 2022-01-01 03:10:00 |

Here is my function to find out outliers for entire dataset

```
def outlierDetection(df): 
   inter_quantile_range = df.approxQuantile("pressure",[0.20,0.80],relativeError=0)
    
    Q1=inter_quantile_range[0]
    Q3=inter_quantile_range[1]
        
    inter_quantile_diff = Q3 - Q1

    minimum_Q1 =  Q1 - 1.5 * inter_quantile_diff
    maximum_Q3 =  Q3 + 1.5 * inter_quantile_diff

    df= df.withColumn("isOutlier",F.when((df["pressure"] > maximum_Q3) | (df["pressure"] < minimum_Q1), 1).otherwise(0))
    return df
```

It is working as expected. but it is considering the outliers for all the values which doesn't fit in the range.

I want to check outlier present for each hourly interval.

I have created another column which has hourly value as follows

| pressure | Timestamp | date_hour |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 358.64 | 2022-01-01 00:00:00 | 2022-01-01 00 |
| 354.98 | 2022-01-01 00:10:00 | 2022-01-01 00 |
| 350.34 | 2022-01-01 00:20:00 | 2022-01-01 00 |
| 429.69 | 2022-01-01 00:30:00 | 2022-01-01 00 |
| 420.41 | 2022-01-01 00:40:00 | 2022-01-01 00 |
| 413.82 | 2022-01-01 00:50:00 | 2022-01-01 00 |
| 409.42 | 2022-01-01 01:00:00 | 2022-01-01 01 |
| 409.67 | 2022-01-01 01:10:00 | 2022-01-01 01 |
| 413.33 | 2022-01-01 01:20:00 | 2022-01-01 01 |
| 405.03 | 2022-01-01 01:30:00 | 2022-01-01 01 |

I am trying to create a window like below.

```
w1= Window.partitionBy("date_hour").orderBy("Timestamp")
```

Is there any way to use my function over each window in the dataframe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using spark 3.1+, you can use [`percentile_approx`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.percentile_approx.html#pyspark-sql-functions-percentile-approx) to calculate the quantiles, and do rest of the calculations in pyspark. In case your spark version does not have that function, we can use an UDF that uses [`numpy.quantile`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.quantile.html) for the quantile calculation. I've shown both in the code.

```
data_sdf = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(data_ls).toDF(['pressure', 'ts']). \
    withColumn('ts', func.col('ts').cast('timestamp')). \
    withColumn('dt_hr', func.date_format('ts', 'yyyyMMddHH'))

# +--------+-------------------+----------+
# |pressure|                 ts|     dt_hr|
# +--------+-------------------+----------+
# |  358.64|2022-01-01 00:00:00|2022010100|
# |  354.98|2022-01-01 00:10:00|2022010100|
# |  350.34|2022-01-01 00:20:00|2022010100|
# |  429.69|2022-01-01 00:30:00|2022010100|
# |  420.41|2022-01-01 00:40:00|2022010100|
# |  413.82|2022-01-01 00:50:00|2022010100|
# |  409.42|2022-01-01 01:00:00|2022010101|
# |  409.67|2022-01-01 01:10:00|2022010101|
# |  413.33|2022-01-01 01:20:00|2022010101|
# |  405.03|2022-01-01 01:30:00|2022010101|
# | 1209.42|2022-01-01 01:40:00|2022010101|
# |  405.03|2022-01-01 01:50:00|2022010101|
# +--------+-------------------+----------+
```

getting the quantiles *(showing both methods; use whichever is available)*

```
# spark 3.1+ has percentile_approx
pressure_quantile_sdf = data_sdf. \
    groupBy('dt_hr'). \
    agg(func.percentile_approx('pressure', [0.2, 0.8]).alias('quantile_20_80'))

# +----------+----------------+
# |     dt_hr|  quantile_20_80|
# +----------+----------------+
# |2022010100|[354.98, 420.41]|
# |2022010101|[405.03, 413.33]|
# +----------+----------------+

# lower versions use UDF
def numpy_quantile_20_80(list_col):
    import numpy as np

    q_20 = np.quantile(list_col, 0.2)
    q_80 = np.quantile(list_col, 0.8)

    return [float(q_20), float(q_80)]

numpy_quantile_20_80_udf = func.udf(numpy_quantile_20_80, ArrayType(FloatType()))

pressure_quantile_sdf = data_sdf. \
    groupBy('dt_hr'). \
    agg(func.collect_list('pressure').alias('pressure_list')). \
    withColumn('quantile_20_80', numpy_quantile_20_80_udf(func.col('pressure_list')))

# +----------+--------------------+----------------+
# |     dt_hr|       pressure_list|  quantile_20_80|
# +----------+--------------------+----------------+
# |2022010100|[358.64, 354.98, ...|[354.98, 420.41]|
# |2022010101|[409.42, 409.67, ...|[405.03, 413.33]|
# +----------+--------------------+----------------+
```

outlier calculation would be easy with the quantile info

```
pressure_quantile_sdf = pressure_quantile_sdf. \
    withColumn('quantile_20', func.col('quantile_20_80')[0]). \
    withColumn('quantile_80', func.col('quantile_20_80')[1]). \
    withColumn('min_q_20', func.col('quantile_20') - 1.5 * (func.col('quantile_80') - func.col('quantile_20'))). \
    withColumn('max_q_80', func.col('quantile_80') + 1.5 * (func.col('quantile_80') - func.col('quantile_20'))). \
    select('dt_hr', 'min_q_20', 'max_q_80')

# +----------+------------------+------------------+
# |     dt_hr|          min_q_20|          max_q_80|
# +----------+------------------+------------------+
# |2022010100|256.83502197265625| 518.5549926757812|
# |2022010101|392.58001708984375|425.77996826171875|
# +----------+------------------+------------------+

# outlier calc -- select columns that are required
data_sdf. \
    join(pressure_quantile_sdf, 'dt_hr', 'left'). \
    withColumn('is_outlier', ((func.col('pressure') > func.col('max_q_80')) | (func.col('pressure') < func.col('min_q_20'))).cast('int')). \
    show()

# +----------+--------+-------------------+------------------+------------------+----------+
# |     dt_hr|pressure|                 ts|          min_q_20|          max_q_80|is_outlier|
# +----------+--------+-------------------+------------------+------------------+----------+
# |2022010100|  358.64|2022-01-01 00:00:00|256.83502197265625| 518.5549926757812|         0|
# |2022010100|  354.98|2022-01-01 00:10:00|256.83502197265625| 518.5549926757812|         0|
# |2022010100|  350.34|2022-01-01 00:20:00|256.83502197265625| 518.5549926757812|         0|
# |2022010100|  429.69|2022-01-01 00:30:00|256.83502197265625| 518.5549926757812|         0|
# |2022010100|  420.41|2022-01-01 00:40:00|256.83502197265625| 518.5549926757812|         0|
# |2022010100|  413.82|2022-01-01 00:50:00|256.83502197265625| 518.5549926757812|         0|
# |2022010101|  409.42|2022-01-01 01:00:00|392.58001708984375|425.77996826171875|         0|
# |2022010101|  409.67|2022-01-01 01:10:00|392.58001708984375|425.77996826171875|         0|
# |2022010101|  413.33|2022-01-01 01:20:00|392.58001708984375|425.77996826171875|         0|
# |2022010101|  405.03|2022-01-01 01:30:00|392.58001708984375|425.77996826171875|         0|
# |2022010101| 1209.42|2022-01-01 01:40:00|392.58001708984375|425.77996826171875|         1|
# |2022010101|  405.03|2022-01-01 01:50:00|392.58001708984375|425.77996826171875|         0|
# +----------+--------+-------------------+------------------+------------------+----------+
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked for me. Although it could not remove all the outliers but majority of them were removed.